# How to exclude groups having alphabetical chars / or capture lines having only numeric chars?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a pattern that matches numeric digits but exclude those which starts with any alphabets/words.

This is the sample text that I am trying to match :

```
    | 30 | 00:45.3 | 00:42.4 | 2.4869 | 5.6578

| event/slno1 | 00:45.3 | 00:42.4 | 2.4869 | 5.6578
| event/slno2 | 00:00.0 | 00:00.0 | 0.0000 | 0.0000
| event/slno3 | 00:45.3 | 00:42.4 | 2.4869 | 5.6578
| event/slno4 | 00:00.0 | 00:00.0 | 0.0000 | 0.0000
```

I wrote this:

```
(\d+)|\s+(\d\d):(\d+\.\d)\s+|(\d\d):(\d+\.\d)\s+|(\d+\.\d+)\s+|(\d+\.\d+)
```

i want to match only the
30 00:45.3 00:42.4 2.4869 5.6578 part  and ignore th rest. How can I ignore the additional matches ?sure how i can negate the other ones.

Here the sample : https://regex101.com/r/ArZB3O/1

Comment: Please be more specific about the desired result for your example. In the first line do you wish to match `"30"`, `"00"`, ... `"5"` and `"6578"`? In the other lines do you wish to match nothing because a letter (`"e"`, for one) precedes  all digits?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^.*event.*$|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\s*(\d\d):(\d+\.\d)` https://regex101.com/r/dYrZkf/1 Or all the numeric values in a single capture group `^.*event.*$|\b((?:\d\d:)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/mBsDPm/1

Comment: No , I want to match only  30 00:45.3 00:42.4 2.4869 5.6578 and ignore the rest.

Comment: @Zerocal With this pattern, you match what you don't want, and capture what you want to keep. So the values that you want are in capture group 1. See https://regex101.com/r/mBsDPm/1 What is the tool or language?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to match whole lines, you should anchor your matches to the beginning and end of lines.  Your input is composed of fields prefixed by a vertical bar, and the ones of interest are the ones that are composed of a sequence of fields that have (to not complicate further on the format of the numeric inputs) digits, colon and dots.  So you can use this regexp to do that:

```
^\s*(\|\s+[0-9:.]+\s*)+$
```

as demonstrated by [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/v3QVGC/1/)  As you matching string started after some whitespace, I have added support for it with the first `\s*`. then it comes a repeating group of one or more sequences of one vertical bar, some whitespace, and some sequence of digits, colons or dots.  If you want to be more precise, you can specify the substructure of `[0-9:.]+` as they follow a pattern, but I think for your problem it is enough with this.